# Function that displays variable numbers from last minute

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a function that will only retain its variable count from the past minute. 
For example, if I call function `count` 100 times, if 60 of those calls were from the past minute, it will only return 60, and not 100.

This is what I have tried so far, making the variable an array and adding numbers to it everytime its called, but I do not know how to remove a count when a minute has passed.

```
var count = 1;
var countArray = [];
```

UPDATE:
I have updated my code with this, but the array elements are not removing as they should,

```
function Count() {
  var jNow = new Date();
  jCountArray.push(jNow);
  for (var i = 0; i <= jCountArray.length; i++) {
    var secondsDiff = (new Date(jNow).getTime() - new Date(jCountArray[i]).getTime()) / 1000;
    if (secondsDiff >= 10) { jCountArray.shift(); }
  }
  console.log(jCountArray);
  return jCountArray.length;
}
```

Comment: Nice, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ASDFGerte i updated my original post!

Comment: What i could think of, is to add timestamps to the array on each call, remove those that are from longer than 60 seconds ago, and use the length of the array as the count.

Comment: @ASDFGerte that is a good observation, I will try and implement this!

Comment: @ASDFGerte I have updated my original post with the current code I have, although I am still facing an issue with the elements not deleting like they are supposed to

Comment: What i had in mind was something like `const Count = (() => { let t = []; return () => { let now = +new Date(); return (t = t.filter(e => now - e <= 60000).concat(now)).length; } })();` (note it's comment code, aka ugly and unformatted, just showing the idea). I'm gone for now, back tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, and the only thing you need `Count` to do is return how many times it was called in the last minute, I think we could do something relatively easily leveraging [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

```js
function getCounter() {
  let count = 0;
  let duration = 60000;
  return function () {
    count = count + 1;
    setTimeout(function () {
      count = count - 1;
    }, duration);
    return count;
  }
}

let counter = getCounter();

function count() {
  console.log(counter());
}
```

```html
<button onclick="count()">Count</button>
```

The only trick here is, to keep the actual `count` private, we need a factory function to wrap it in a closure.  If that's unimportant you can write it as a simple function and keep the count in the parent scope.  Also, for testing purposes you can change the `duration` to a lower millisecond count to see it in action.